# Using SwiftUI, Combine, and Firebase, how do I verify that a user is signed in anonymously before linking their account to an email/password?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I have an AuthService with the following functions:

```
func signInAnon() -> AnyPublisher<User, AuthError> {
    return Future<User, AuthError> { promise in
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                return promise(.failure(.signInAnon(description: error.localizedDescription)))
            } else if let user = result?.user {
                return promise(.success(user))
            }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

func linkAccount(email: String, password: String) -> AnyPublisher<User, AuthError> {
    
    let emailCredential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: email, password: password)
    
    return Future<User, AuthError> { promise in
        Auth.auth().currentUser?.link(with: emailCredential) { result, error in
            if let error = error {
                return promise(.failure(.linkAccount(description: error.localizedDescription)))
            } else if let user = result?.user {
                Auth.auth().updateCurrentUser(user) { error in
                    if let error = error {
                        return promise(.failure(.updateCurrentUser(description: error.localizedDescription)))
                    } else {
                        return promise(.success((user)))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

In my ViewModel, I want to link the user's anonymous account with an email/password credential. However, at the point of sign in, anonymous sign in has not happened.

Here is the code in my ViewModel:

```swift
case .signUp:

isLoading = true

authService.signInAnon()
    .timeout(.seconds(5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, options: nil, customError: { () -> AuthError in
        return .signInAnon(description: self.error?.localizedDescription)})
    .sink { completion in
        switch completion {
        case let .failure(error):
            self.error = error
        case .finished:
            print("User signed in anonymously")
            self.error = nil
            }
    } receiveValue: { user in
        self.user = user
    }
    .store(in: &cancellables)

authService.linkAccount(email: email, password: password)
    .timeout(.seconds(5), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main, options: nil, customError: { () -> AuthError in
        return .linkAccount(description: self.error?.localizedDescription)})
    .sink { completion in
    self.isLoading = false
    switch completion {
    case let .failure(error):
        self.error = error
        self.alertIsPresented = true
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    case .finished:
        print("Sign up successful")
    }
} receiveValue: { user in
    self.user = user
}
.store(in: &cancellables)
```

I am running into problems because sometimes the function linking the accounts finishes before the anonymous sign in function, presenting an error.

How can I write this conditionally so that there is a check to see if the user is signed in anonymously? If they are, link their account. If they are not, sign them in anonymously, and then link their account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my recommendation for how to use Firebase Anonymous Auth:

1. As soon as your app has launched, initialise Firebase and check if *a* user is signed in. If a user has previously signed in, Firebase Auth will have fetched that user on time before you call this method.
2. If no user is present, sign in anonymously.
3. You can then start using all Firebase services that benefit from a signed-in user (such as Firestore)
4. Once the user decides to actually sign in, use any Firebase Authentication provider to get a token, and link that to the existing anonymous user. BTW, I recommend using something more secure than Email/Password.

Sample code for performing anonymous sign-in at app start-up (taken from [this sample app](https://github.com/peterfriese/MakeItSo/blob/master/code/frontend/iOS/MakeItSo/MakeItSo/Services/AuthenticationService.swift#L26)):

```swift
func signIn() {
  if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
    Auth.auth().signInAnonymously()
  }
}
```

Sample code for upgrading to a Sign in with Apple account (taken from [the same sample app](https://github.com/peterfriese/MakeItSo/blob/master/code/frontend/iOS/MakeItSo/MakeItSo/Services/AuthenticationService.swift#L173)):

```swift
      case .link:
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
          currentUser.link(with: credential) { (result, error) in
            if let error = error, (error as NSError).code == AuthErrorCode.credentialAlreadyInUse.rawValue {
              print("The user you're signing in with has already been linked, signing in to the new user and migrating the anonymous users [\(currentUser.uid)] tasks.")
              
              if let updatedCredential = (error as NSError).userInfo[AuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey] as? OAuthCredential {
                print("Signing in using the updated credentials")
                Auth.auth().signIn(with: updatedCredential) { (result, error) in
                  if let user = result?.user {
                    currentUser.getIDToken { (token, error) in
                      if let idToken = token {
                        (self.taskRepository as? FirestoreTaskRepository)?.migrateTasks(from: idToken)
                        self.doSignIn(appleIDCredential: appleIDCredential, user: user)
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            else if let error = error {
              print("Error trying to link user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            else {
              if let user = result?.user {
                self.doSignIn(appleIDCredential: appleIDCredential, user: user)
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

If you're interested in how this would like for Combine, we've started implementing Combine support for Firebase - check out our [project tracker](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/projects/3)

Comment: Peter, I've been watching your videos on YouTube! This is incredibly helpful. I pretty much ended up implementing your recommendation. I will definitely check out the combine support project. Thank you!

Comment: The problem with this approach is if the user has been logged in on a different device first, which is exactly why they’d log in again: To retrieve their old content. 

In this case, linking will not work, because the account is “already being used”. Unfortunately I have no fix to that, which is why I’m currently browsing SO.

Comment: If a user has logged in on another device previously with _Anonymous Auth_, you will not be able to retrieve their user ID on a new device. They need to link their account to email or one of the federated IdPs first on the other device first. See this article https://peterfriese.dev/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part4/ for more details. @lmunck, feel free to open a new question if you don't find the answer to your specific situation.

Comment: Thank you, I did but it was phrased rather convoluted, so I’m currently trying to learn enough to phrase it in a better way. My issue is when you’ve logged in on device A with Google/Apple, and then try to link your account on device B. In that case I get a “user already has an account” error when trying to link.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68145638/where-in-firebase-login-process-do-i-check-migrate-existing-content/68145855?noredirect=1#comment120452045_68145855

Comment: And I love your demo app, but I get confused about your use of Resolver. It’s sounds intriguing but I can’t seem to wrap my head around it.