# Where in Firebase login process, do I check/migrate existing content?

Tags: swiftui, firebase-authentication

I have a SwiftUI/Firebase project, where I allow users to create and upload content while logged in with anonymous. I also have a Firebase rule that prevent editing data that isn't tagged with the same UID as you're logged in with.

My problem is that, when users log in with Google or Apple login, I don't know where to insert any logic for migrating their content from their old anonymous UID to their Apple/Google UID. (Update: Yes, I can link accounts, but that only works if they haven't previously used their account on a different device).

As far as I can tell, I don't get their new Apple/Google UID until after they're authenticated, and by then, they can no longer modify data tagged with the Anonymous UID.

I've tried linking the accounts, but I get an "Account is already linked" error, so I'm assuming that approach is a dead end?

As an example, here is my code for the Google login with a note where I'm trying to insert my migration logic:

```
        import SwiftUI
        import Firebase
        import GoogleSignIn

        struct GoogleSignInButton: View {
            
            @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: GoogleSignInViewModel
            
            var body: some View {
                Button("Sign in with Google") {
                    viewModel.signIn()
                }
                .foregroundColor(Color.greyZ)
                .padding()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.greyB)
                .cornerRadius(5)
                .padding()
            }
        }

        struct GoogleSignInButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
            static var previews: some View {
                GoogleSignInButton()
            }
        }


        class GoogleSignInViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
            
            enum SignInState {
                case signedIn
                case signedOut
            }
            
            @Published var state: SignInState = .signedOut
            
            override init() {
                super.init()
                
                setupGoogleSignIn()
            }
            
            func signIn() {
                if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser == nil {
                    
                    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
                    
                    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
                }
            }
            
            func signOut() {
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
                
                do {
                    try Auth.auth().signOut()
                    
                    state = .signedOut
                } catch let signOutError as NSError {
                    print(signOutError.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            
            private func setupGoogleSignIn() {
                GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
            }
        }


        extension GoogleSignInViewModel: GIDSignInDelegate {
            
            func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
                if error == nil {
                    
                    // Get UID of existing user
                    if let previousUID:String = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
                        // migrate Firestore data for old uid to new uid
                        // Firebase rule prevent modifying data if you're logged in with different uid so it has to be before logging in with Google
                        // But I don't seem to have the new Google UID yet, so what do I migrate it to?
                    }
                    
                    // Log in with new user
                    firebaseAuthentication(withUser: user)
                } else {
                    print(error.debugDescription)
                }
            }
            
            private func firebaseAuthentication(withUser user: GIDGoogleUser) {
                
                if let authentication = user.authentication {
                    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
                    
                    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (_, error) in
                        if let error = error {
                            print(error.localizedDescription)
                            self.state = .signedOut
                        } else {
                            self.state = .signedIn
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

UPDATE: As requested, here is the Link-function that invariably results in a "This credential is already associated with a different user account" error. I have checked the account in Firebase, and the account already exists, so that is why I assumed the "link" approach is a dead end, and tried migrating the data instead.

```
private func firebaseAuthentication(withUser user: GIDGoogleUser) {
                
                if let authentication = user.authentication {
                    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
                    
                    if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                        // User already logged in
                        currentUser.link(with: credential) { result, error in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            } else {
                                
                                print(result ?? "Success")
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                        
                    } else {
                        
                        // User not logged in (shouldn't happen as they're always anonymous
                        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (_, error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                                self.state = .signedOut
                            } else {
                                self.state = .signedIn
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of migrating the data, consider linking the user's new Google or Apple  credentials to their existing Firebase account by filling the process outlines in [linking multiple Auth providers to an account on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking).

Comment: "I've tried linking the accounts, but I get an "Account is already linked" error, so I'm assuming that approach is a dead end?"

Comment: I can try adding that code also if you think that's the way forward.

Comment: If the accounts are already linked, the user should have only a single UID. What is the problem that you're still trying to solve in that case? Is there data under another UID in a database? If so, you will indeed have to migrate that data over to their new UID, and you'll have to do this from a trusted environment (like your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions).

Comment: Sorry, I can see my question was unclearly stared. When a user logs in on device A and creates some content, linking works just fine. But when they start using device B, create some content there as anonymous and then want to log in again to retrieve their old content from device A, I get “user already exist” when trying to link them.

Comment: Ah yeah, that indeed leads to duplicate accounts, and the need for data migration.

Comment: BTW, this is exactly what I described here: https://peterfriese.dev/replicating-reminder-swiftui-firebase-part4/#how-can-we-resolve-this-situation.

Comment: Thanks @PeterFriese! Putting it on my reading list. 

Comment: Yes, I’ve been reading that too @PeterFriese and it’s a great post on exactly this. In fact I’d love to use it. My only issue is that I am completely unable to wrap my head around Resolver and what role it plays in that code.

Comment: @lmunck Resolver is a dependency injection container and I needed it because it made it easier to wire up all the services in my app. Sorry to hear it is making things more difficult to understand. Feel free to start a new discussion in https://github.com/peterfriese/MakeItSo/discussions/categories/q-a and I will do my best to answer your questions. The more specific your questions, the better I know how to help.

Comment: @PeterFriese Great article. Went over it, and it seems like the same approach I have implemented for my app. However, there is some edge case that I am unable to handle. For example, sometimes, the sign in succeeds, but user closes the app or looses network connectivity before calling the migrate api, which causes them the loose the tasks that they did. How do you deal this this?

Comment: To make this more fail-save, I would recommend creating a marker document that triggers a Cloud Function that performs the migration. The client can then check the document to determine if the migration is still in flight or has finished, and then act accordingly.